# Using drawables xml files and images

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-drawable, android-design-library

How is someone supposed to use the drawables located in ...\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res in Android Studio projects?

For example, if someone would like to change the Floating Action Button icon to a pencil icon, what is the standard practice?

Is there some kind of documentation available that demonstrates what each drawable XML file actually looks like when drawn? Or are you expected to copy and paste these into your project in order to see what they actually draw?

Surely there is some kind of gallery somewhere...

Comment: You should provide drawables in your app's res folder. In the case of a FAB, you set the src field in the FAB: android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"

Comment: Since you specify android-22 I assume you want some of the new Material Design icons, like the pencil icon. You can find them at https://design.google.com/icons/

Comment: Thanks a lot. As for the icons already available in Android's res folder, is the developer simply supposed to know what these XML files draw off by heart or is there some documentation explaining which XML pertains to which icon?

Comment: I've never touched them. I didn't know these XML files existed until reading this question. As far as I can tell, these are internal files used by the android sdk to draw Views, and a developer should never use them. What did you need them for?

Comment: @android:drawable/drawableName - this lets you choose drawables from SDk/framework but you can't choose all the available Drawables. Say you have set Min SDK to 16 and Max to 23. Than you can't use Drawable which are only present on or after 17 as Users win API16 won't have those thus causing force closes. The best bet is to manually copy the required drawables to your apps local directory and than reference using @drawable/drawableName.

Comment: I'd like to add icons to my application and change the Floating Action Button icon to be appropriate for the task it is used for. I guess I wrongly assumed that the developer was meant to use the xml files rather than png. If you use an Android template that contains a Floating Action Button design widget, it will have a default icon. I'm pretty certain it referes to the XML file. For example,         android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat". This is what makes me believe that I should be referencing an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike any other O.S, Android powers billion devices with different screen sizes, ranging from small phones to large TV sets. And it becomes a primary necessity to run apps with perfect User Experience on all sorts of devices! And for that purpose Android uses `DIP` or `DP` (Display Independent Pixels).

And coming to the solution to your question, [consider reading from here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

And, the general procedure is to generate images of different resolutions for different screen sizes, [see this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Also, this [video](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/implementing-designs-for-android/starting-with-design-mockups/supporting-multiple-screens) explains it simple!

And in order to generate multiple images with different resolutions for the respective screen sizes, I personally use a resizer tool. [Final Android resizer, available here.](https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer)

hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not sure the OP asked anything about screen size support.

Comment: Still a great answer. I rarely have any of my Android questions answered on this site.